# ¿Como disparar un evento en el componente padre desde un componente hijo en angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

estaba pensando en que forma podria disparan un evento en un componete padre en algular pero no se bien cual seria la sintaxis.

Estoy trabajando con formularios y tengo un custon input que estoy uniendo con la interfaz ControlValueAccesor, lo que quisiera hacer es dispara el evento  fromTheSon()  de el formulario padre

pense hacerlo con una directiva output pero no se como se como hacerlo realmente, se emitir valores pero no como dispara una funcion en el padre.

ESte el componeten padre

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component, OnDestroy, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormControl, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-registration-form',
  templateUrl: './registration-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registration-form.component.scss']
})
export class RegistrationFormComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  dynamicFormArray: any;
  registrationForm!: FormGroup;
  triguerRef: Subscription | any;
  private subscriptions: Subscription[] | any = [];



  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private fb: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    // se incializa el formGroup vacio;
    this.registrationForm = this.fb.group({});
    this.httpClient.get('http://localhost:3000/form').subscribe(data => {
      this.dynamicFormArray = data;
      this.createFormControl();
      this.createFormListener();
      // this.createFormValidators();
    });
  }

  createFormControl(): void {
    // recorre el array para ir creando los controles
    this.dynamicFormArray.forEach((element: any) => {

      if (element.Required) {

        this.registrationForm.addControl(element.ID, new FormControl(element.Value, {
          validators: [Validators.required],
          updateOn: element.Control,
        }));
      } else {
        this.registrationForm.addControl(element.ID, new FormControl(''));
      }
    });

    console.log(this.registrationForm);
  }   


  fromTheSon() {
    console.log('Hellow');
  }

  showStatus(): void {
    if (this.registrationForm.valid) {
      alert('Formulario enviado');
    } else {
      alert('Formulario no valido');
    }
  }    
}
```

HTML del padre

```
<div *ngSwitchCase="'custom'">
      <div class="col-md-6 mt-2">
           <app-custom-input [formControlName]="control.ID"></app-custom-input>
        </div>
 </div>
```

y este el hijo

```
import { Component, OnInit, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ControlValueAccessor, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-input',
  templateUrl: './custom-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CustomInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CustomInputComponent implements OnInit, ControlValueAccessor {

  currentValue = 1;
  onChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouch = () => { };
  isDisabled!: boolean;
  messages!: string |null;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  add() {
    if (this.currentValue >= 8) {
      this.showMessage('You cannot have more than 8 Warehouse')
      return;
    }

    this.currentValue = this.currentValue + 1;
    // this.onTouch();
    // this.onChange(this.currentValue);
  }

  sub() {
    if (this.currentValue < 2) {
      this.showMessage('You need at least one');
      this.currentValue = 1;
      return;
    }
    this.currentValue = this.currentValue - 1;
    this.onTouch();
    this.onChange(this.currentValue);
  }

  writeValue(value: number): void {
    if (value) {
      this.currentValue = value;
    }
  }

  // Interface methods
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    this.isDisabled = isDisabled;
  }

  showMessage(mensaje: string) {
    this.messages = mensaje;
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.messages = null;
    }, 3000);
  }

}
```

Comment: Para emitir los valores de hijo a padre si usas un output, en el hijo instancias la clase eventChange = EventEmitter<T>();, en el hijo agregas el eventChange.emit() la action (metodo) que disparara el evento, metodo(){ this.evenChange.emit(valor) }, en el componente `<custom-input evenChange="fromTheSon($event)"></custom-input>`, y ya en el padre, en tu funcion obtienes el evento del hijo `fromTheSon(event){...}`

Comment: Aca un [ejemplo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-rgeyeh?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para lograr emitir un evento desde el componente hijo, tienes que crear un *evenEmiter* de la siguiente manera:

```
@Output() eventoHijo: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Donde *eventoHijo* lo vas a declarar en el decorador de llamada en el padre:

```
<app-componente-hijo (eventoHijo)="changeItem($event)"></app-componente-hijo>
```

Además debes implementar el método en tu TypeScript:

```
changeItem($evento){Tu lógica}
```